# I don't know how to write the on/off code according to buzzer's conditions

Tags: python

The code below is a code that activates the buzzer by detecting eye blinking. However, if the code rings while satisfying the conditions, it does not turn off. I hope the buzzer stops working when I open my eyes. I don't know where and how to modify it.

A few seconds after the value of ear becomes 0.1x, the buzzer is supposed to work. I don't want the buzzer to work when the value of ear is 0.2 or higher.

```
# import the necessary packages
    from imutils.video import VideoStream
    from imutils import face_utils
    import numpy as np
    import argparse
    import imutils
    import time
    import dlib
    import cv2
    
    def euclidean_dist(ptA, ptB):
        # compute and return the euclidean distance between the two
        # points
        return np.linalg.norm(ptA - ptB)
    
    def eye_aspect_ratio(eye):
        # compute the euclidean distances between the two sets of
        # vertical eye landmarks (x, y)-coordinates
        A = euclidean_dist(eye[1], eye[5])
        B = euclidean_dist(eye[2], eye[4])
        # compute the euclidean distance between the horizontal
        # eye landmark (x, y)-coordinates
        C = euclidean_dist(eye[0], eye[3])
        # compute the eye aspect ratio
        ear = (A + B) / (2.0 * C)
        # return the eye aspect ratio
        return ear
    
    # construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-c", "--cascade", required=True,
        help = "path to where the face cascade resides")
    ap.add_argument("-p", "--shape-predictor", required=True,
        help="path to facial landmark predictor")
    ap.add_argument("-a", "--alarm", type=int, default=0,
        help="boolean used to indicate if TrafficHat should be used")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())
    
    # check to see if we are using GPIO/TrafficHat as an alarm
    if args["alarm"] > 0:
        import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
        GPIO.setwarnings(False)
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        buzzer=18
        GPIO.setup(buzzer,GPIO.OUT)
        print("[INFO] using buzzer alarm...")
        
    # 두 개의 상수를 정의합니다. 하나는 표시할 눈 종횡비에 대한 것
    # 깜박이고 연속된 횟수에 대한 두 번째 상수
    # 프레임 눈은 시작하기 위한 임계값 아래에 있어야 함
    # 알람
    EYE_AR_THRESH = 0.3
    EYE_AR_CONSEC_FRAMES = 16
    # 프레임 카운터와 부울 초기화
    # 알람이 울리는지 여부를 나타냄
    COUNTER = 0
    ALARM_ON = False
    
    # load OpenCV's Haar cascade for face detection (which is faster than
    # dlib's built-in HOG detector, but less accurate), then create the
    # facial landmark predictor
    print("[INFO] loading facial landmark predictor...")
    detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier(args["cascade"])
    predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(args["shape_predictor"])
    
    # 왼쪽 얼굴 랜드마크의 인덱스를 잡고
    # 오른쪽 눈, 각각
    (lStart, lEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["left_eye"]
    (rStart, rEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["right_eye"]
    
    # start the video stream thread
    print("[INFO] starting video stream thread...")
    vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
    # vs = VideoStream(usePiCamera=True).start()
    time.sleep(1.0)
    
    while True:
        # grab the frame from the threaded video file stream, resize
        # it, and convert it to grayscale
        # channels)
        frame = vs.read()
        frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=450)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # detect faces in the grayscale frame
        rects = detector.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.1, 
            minNeighbors=5, minSize=(30, 30),
            flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
        
        # loop over the face detections
        for (x, y, w, h) in rects:
            # construct a dlib rectangle object from the Haar cascade
            # bounding box
            rect = dlib.rectangle(int(x), int(y), int(x + w),
                int(y + h))
            
            # determine the facial landmarks for the face region, then
            # convert the facial landmark (x, y)-coordinates to a NumPy
            # array
            shape = predictor(gray, rect)
            shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)
            
            # extract the left and right eye coordinates, then use the
            # coordinates to compute the eye aspect ratio for both eyes
            leftEye = shape[lStart:lEnd]
            rightEye = shape[rStart:rEnd]
            leftEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(leftEye)
            rightEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(rightEye)
            # average the eye aspect ratio together for both eyes
            ear = (leftEAR + rightEAR) / 2.0
            
            # compute the convex hull for the left and right eye, then
            # visualize each of the eyes
            leftEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(leftEye)
            rightEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(rightEye)
            cv2.drawContours(frame, [leftEyeHull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
            cv2.drawContours(frame, [rightEyeHull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
            
            # check to see if the eye aspect ratio is below the blink
            # threshold, and if so, increment the blink frame counter
            if ear < EYE_AR_THRESH:
                COUNTER += 1
                
                # if the eyes were closed for a sufficient number of
                # frames, then sound the alarm
                if COUNTER >= EYE_AR_CONSEC_FRAMES:
                    # if the alarm is not on, turn it on
                    if not ALARM_ON:
                        ALARM_ON = True
                        
                        # check to see if the TrafficHat buzzer should
                        # be sounded
                        if args["alarm"] > 0:
                            GPIO.output(buzzer, GPIO.HIGH)
                            sleep(0.5)
                            GPIO.output(buzzer, GPIO.LOW)
                            sleep(1)
                            
                    # draw an alarm on the frame
                    cv2.putText(frame, "DROWSINESS ALERT!", (10, 30),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                    
            # otherwise, the eye aspect ratio is not below the blink
            # threshold, so reset the counter and alarm
            else:
                COUNTER = 0
                ALARM_ON = False
                
                # draw the computed eye aspect ratio on the frame to help
            # with debugging and setting the correct eye aspect ratio
            # thresholds and frame counters
            cv2.putText(frame, "EAR: {:.3f}".format(ear), (300, 30),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
     
        # show the frame
        cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
     
        # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
        if key == ord("q"):
            break
        
    # do a bit of cleanup
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    vs.stop()
```